# iphone/objective c (simple) question

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to avoid the redeclaration of self, in the following

```
picker2.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// showing the picker
[self presentModalViewController:picker2 animated:YES];
```

Why am i not able to just go like:

```
[picker2.peoplePickerDelegate presentModalViewController:picker2 animated:YES];
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `picker2.peoplePickerDelegate` may not be `self` before your assignment.

(Also, `picker2.peoplePickerDelegate` is not a `UIViewController` so sending the `-presentModalViewController:animated:` message to it is wrong.)

Comment: hmm, i think i confused myself doing that, I thought self was being redeclared, where its not. it was to help answer my bigger question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150874/iphone-sdk-bringing-up-viewcontroller-in-shouldcontinueafterselectingperson.
I am having trouble bringing up a view controller after being in contact list, and i think it has something to do with self. Can you look at that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should think of one thing also.

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker2 animated:YES];
```

It will work because presentmodalviewcontroller is a method of UIViewController class and

in the method `[picker2.peoplePickerDelegate presentModalViewController:picker2 animated:YES];`

you are trying to call it with a `(id)` type i.e. it will be inheritting from a NSObject.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup